# How to solve duplicate page content issue for similar pages

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I am using wordpress. In that I need to show location page for 10 different locations.

So I have created one theme for that.

In that sidebar that 10 location's vertical menu is there. And then that location's map is there. And in right side that location's address is there. Each page is having different page titles.

As per location name in url my code is fetching the address and name for that location and then I m displaying that.

I m using SEOmoz for SEO. So in that it is showing all those 10 pages are having duplicate page content. So how to resolve this error?

The page structure is as follows.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="wrapperDiv">
<div class="bg">
<aside>
<h2>Locations</h2>
            <span>
                <ul class="matt">
                    <li <?php if(is_page('Locations')) echo 'class="current_page_item"'; ?>><a href="/locations/">Overview</a></li>
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'depth'        => 1,
                        'show_date'    => '',
                        'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
                        'child_of'     => 19,
                        'exclude'      => '',
                        'include'      => '',
                        'title_li'     => '',
                        'echo'         => 1,
                        'authors'      => '',
                        'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
                        'link_before'  => '',
                        'link_after'   => '',
                        'walker'       => '',
                        'post_status'  => 'publish' 
                    ); 

                    wp_list_pages( $args );
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </aside>
        <article class="locations">
            <div id="smallnav">
             <?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>
            </div>
            <h2>Location : <?php echo $p->name;?></h2>
            <div class="entry-content-locations">
            <?php
    echo '<div id="map"><div id="mapss" style="height:100%; width:100%; float:left;"> </div></div>';

            ?>
                <div id="spanLocs" class="spanLoc"></div>                               
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->           
            </div>          
        </article>                     
        </div>
</div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Code for google map + Code to fill address in spanLoc  
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It is better to provide a working example or at least an image.

Answer (score 0):

You have two redundant ending div tags (Last ones). Try removing them and see what happens. Something like this:

```
....
<div id="spanLocs" class="spanLoc"></div>
</div>
<!-- .entry-content -->
</div>
</article>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Code for google map + Code to fill address in spanLoc  
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```